# Cache location with gitlab-runner and docker executor on Windows?

Tags: docker, caching, gitlab, gitlab-runner

Where are the zips of the job caches when running gitlab-runner on Windows with docker executor ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found on the computer executing gitlab-runner, which has a more or less default configuration:

```
C:\ProgramData\docker\volumes\<runner-id>\_data\<path\to\repo>\<cache key>-N\cache.zip
```

With:

- `<cache key>` the value of the cache key provided from `.gitlab-ci.yml`.
- `N` an integer close to 1, possibly due to parallel builds (?). I think that sometimes the directory name is simply `<cache key>`.